# What is the meaning of # in this url - http://projectname/controller/viewname#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, model-view-controller

On clicking the submit button of a asp.net mvc webpage, it does not show any change other than #sign succeeds my webpage url like this - http://projectname/controller/viewname#  Why?

Answer (score 0):

It refers to a specific anchor in the source page.

I wouldn't worry about it